# Two-Observer Spacetime Diagram

Tags: relativity

What is the significant in a two-observer spacetime diagram's primed axes? More specifically, the area enclosed by them. Obviously, if an event occurs within the axes, it is simple to find its relative time and position by drawing parallel lines. But what if the event is outside of the axes? What is its significance? How does one calculate (graphically) its relative time and position in the home frame?

Comment: Could you provide a drawing with a concrete example? It would be easier to answer your question, and possibly you will be able to resolve the problem by yourself, just by considering one particular case. - In a general way, Lorentz transforms (and Minkowski diagrams) permit the exhaustive transform from one frame to another.

Comment: What is "two-observer spacetime"? Each observer with his/her spacetime. If the two observers move one relatively to the other, the space and the time behave differently for each one.

Comment: http://www.phas.ubc.ca/~mav/p200/stnotes.pdf